# How do I use pyinstaller to package a large multi-folder project?

Tags: import, module, pyinstaller, executable

Here is an example project folder structure similar to my actual project.

```
-repo_folder
--app_folder
---GUI_folder
----GUI1.py
----GUI2.py
---calculations_folder
----calculations1.py
----calculations2.py
---main.py
--cli.py
```

cli.py points to main.py. Main.py only import GUI1.py. And from there GUI2.py is imported and so on.

Basically, is there an easy way to make sure that all the importing done in each file is included? I have not been able to succesfully export a project with this kind of folder setup succesfully using pyinstaller. I keep getting "Failed to execute script cli" or "No module named GUI".

Could someone make an example of how the code would be import for a project structured like the above?

Comment: Could you please confirm your error message. Since there is no GUI module in your project it is normal the you have a No module named GUI

Comment: Ah, in the example here I just made up some random GUI related .py files. In the error message is supposed to be "No module named GUI1". However, now I have managed to alleviate the error and instead come across a similar FileNotFoundError...

Comment: If you could provide the full error and the related pieces of code it would be helpful.